# Оптимизированная адаптивная карусель

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите код оптимизированной (быстрой по скорости загрузки) карусели через html-css-JQuery (возможно JS). Нужно чтобы было 4 слайда с двумя переключателями по бокам и нижними переключателями на любой слайд по выбору.

Comment: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/demos.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) - реально очень удобная и быстрая каруселька. Для того, чтобы сделать вторую карусель с переключателями на любой слайд, можно сделать вторую карусель и ораганизовать переключение через метод `slickGoTo`.
Например, каждому слайду в нижней карусельке присвоить `data-id` с порядковыми номерами слайдов, а через обработку клика брать этот `data-id` и использовать метод. Например:

```
$('.slider-item').click(function() {
   var target = $(this).data('id')
   $('.mainSlider').slick('slickGoTo', target)
})
```